# DHT 11 sensors and i2c LCD to Wemos Wifi not Working

Tags: lcd, temperature-sensor, print

Its my first time make arduino project. I make wemos d1  project using DHT11 temperature sensor and LCD 20x4 with i2c. **The temperature data will display in LCD and sending to the bot telegram.** **For sending to the bot telegram it works, but why the data cannot display to the LCD?** When I tried common charachter like "Hello World!" in the LCD it works. Can you help me? What should I do? Thanks before.

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F,2,1,0,4,5,6,7,3, POSITIVE);
#define DHTPIN D14  
#define DHTTYPE DHT11   

byte degree[8] = {
  0b00110,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000
};

DHT dht(D14, DHT11);

void setup() {
  lcd.createChar(0, degree);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("DHT11 test!");
  lcd.begin (20, 4);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(2000);
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
  lcd.print("Humi : ");
  lcd.print(h); 
  lcd.print(" %");

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Temp : ");
  lcd.print(t);
  lcd.print(" C");  
}
```

Comment: what you should do is to give us more information. so far, all you have said is that your project does not work. you posted no circuit diagram and no code, so it is impossible to even guess what the problem might be.

Comment: Will you show us your code please, or is it "top secret"?

Comment: please add the code to your question and delete these comments ... i do not think that anyone will be able to read your code in comments

Comment: I've been add my code at my question. thank you very well

Comment: Please define "not working". Does nothing at all get displayed?

Comment: Does nothing at all

Comment: We would expect at least that `Humi : ` would be displayed, so this is nothing to do with your DHT11 sensor. Unless ... try putting in a debugging print after getting the sensor data. Like: `Serial.println (h);`

Comment: Ya, I've tried to see is that any problems with DHT11 sensor by serial monitor, the sensor works good. But when I connect it to the lcd, it doesnt work. it's confusing. Anyway, thank you for the response,

Comment: what is D14? Wemos doesn't have pin D14

Comment: what is LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F,2,1,0,4,5,6,7,3, POSITIVE)? I can't find such a constructor.

Comment: D14 is a SDA pin in wemos, and LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F,2,1,0,4,5,6,7,3, POSITIVE) is lcd initiation based on i2c library.

Comment: Does wemos cannot display temperature data in the lcd? I think it should be fine but why still error. For i2c wire I connect VCC to 5V, GND to GND, SDA pin to D4 and SCL pin to D3.

Comment: Oh I see, I cannot connect DHT11 to the D14 pin, because it is used for SDA(D14/SDA/D4). when I move to the pin D2, it works. Thank you every one. Sorry if I make mistake because it is my first project.

Comment: @ChoirinNisa, it is not D4, only io 4. D4 is io 2. I formulated an answer, for future readers. You could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Constant `D14` is for Wemos D1 and other esp8266 dev boards mapped in arduino core to esp8266 io pin 4. Pin 4 is used as I2C SDA pin. The LCD uses I2C so pin 4 (D14) can't be used for the sensor.

from `pins_arduino.h` for Wemos D1 R1:

```
#define PIN_WIRE_SDA (4)
#define PIN_WIRE_SCL (5)

static const uint8_t D14  = 4;
static const uint8_t D15  = 5;
```

The origin of this confusing esp8266 io pin to Dx constants mapping is the big Wemos D1. There are esp8266 pins mapped to standard Uno pinout.

[image]